# Strange performance issue C# and RabbitMq

Tags: c#, wcf, rabbitmq, castle-windsor

**Background:**

I have developed a couple of WCF services for importing data. When receiving data my services publishes the request on an EasyNetQ service bus, hooked up to an RabbitMq server.

The consumer then takes the request, serializes it to XML and sends it as an parameter to a stored procedure for handling. The stored procedure in turn, performs a table merge for inserting or updating the data.

**The Problem:**

My problem is that i sometimes can ack quite a good amount of messages/sec and sometimes got very poor performance, which in turn leads my queues to build up in RabbitMq.

**My application uses the following technologies:**

- TopShelf for hosting the web services.
- Windsor Dependency Injection
- Interceptors for logging, handling exceptions and timing performance.
- EasyNetQ as message bus.
- RabbitMq as message broker.

**I have tried following things:**

- Executed same message several times and it seems that
  the execution time varies strongly. When executing the stored
  procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, the execution time is
  about the same for all repetitions.
- Wired up my solution against a local RabbitMq server and a local
  database.
- Removed interceptors for transaction handling.
- Changed my db connection class from creating\opening a new connection
  for each call to reuse the existing connection (removed using
  statement for sql connection).

*Does anyone have any ideas of what could be causing my problem?*

Thanx in advance.
Matias

Comment: You should definitely log wherever possible and narrow down the bottleneck to a very specific spot in your pipeline. Without it, you can only guess. Since the pipeline spans multiple subsystems and technologies, the bottleneck can be anywhere.

Comment: It could be any number of things. I would follow @WiktorZychla's advice and try to narrow down the bottle neck with logging. You could also try removing specific pieces of your pipeline. A good DBA should be able to look at the SQL Server profiling tools and tell you where you might be suffering from poor performance. The EasyNetQ message dispatcher runs on a single thread, so you might want to experiment with the async subscribe method and async database IO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the slowness comes from rabbit - check the I/O of the disk in case you are keeping your messages durable and persisted, in case you are not involving disk, check the memory watermarks, in case you running high on memory, rabbit will flush it's messages to disk, this will lead to significant slowness during this process.